# Why does Google give me back 'none' coordinates

Tags: python, api, jupyter

So I'm trying to get the coordinates for Glasgow and I am trying to use the google maps API. However, the functions returns None and None as coordinates and I don't quite understand why. I'm assuming I have the wrong parameter somewhere. Code below.

```
import requests
api_key = api key
google_api_key = api key
def get_coordinates(api_key, address, verbose=False):
    try:
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={}&address={}'.format(api_key, address)
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        if verbose:
            print('Google Maps API JSON result =>', response)
        results = response['results']
        geographical_data = results[0]['geometry']['location'] # get geographical coordinates
        lat = geographical_data['lat']
        lon = geographical_data['lng']
        return [lat, lon]
    except:
        return [None, None]

address = 'Glasgow, United Kingdom'
glasgow_centre = get_coordinates(google_api_key, address)
print('Coordinate of {}: {}'.format(address, glasgow_centre))
```

Comment: Don't do bare `except`, do at least `except Exception as e` and print `e` to see what happened

Comment: Add a `raise` directly over `return [None, None]` to re-raise the exception for debugging. For production add logging. From The Zen of Python: "Errors should never pass silently."

Comment: So I added the raise and it gives me an Index error: list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The index error is happening because you don't have any results.

Log the response to see what error message you're getting. This is what happened for me:

{'error_message': 'This API project is not authorized to use this API.', 'results': [], 'status': 'REQUEST_DENIED'}